# How can i generate a single page pdf file with array of images in ios?

Tags: ios

I need to generate a PDF file file with array of image I have tried so many types of code but I am not getting the solution can any body help me please.

I tried below code.

```
- (void)createPDFWithImagesArray:(NSMutableArray *)array andFileName:(NSString *)fileName
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *PDFPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",fileName]];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(PDFPath, CGRectZero, nil);
for (UIImage *image in array)
{
    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), nil);

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
}
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

but it is not helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
  [self setupPDFDocumentNamed:@"NewPDF" Width:850 Height:1100];

[self beginPDFPage];

CGRect textRect = [self addText:@"This is some nice text here, don't you agree?" 
                      withFrame:CGRectMake(kPadding, kPadding, 400, 200) fontSize:48.0f];

CGRect blueLineRect = [self addLineWithFrame:CGRectMake(kPadding, textRect.origin.y + textRect.size.height + kPadding, _pageSize.width - kPadding*2, 4) 
                                   withColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"];
CGRect imageRect = [self addImage:anImage 
                          atPoint:CGPointMake((_pageSize.width/2)-(anImage.size.width/2), blueLineRect.origin.y + blueLineRect.size.height + kPadding)];

[self addLineWithFrame:CGRectMake(kPadding, imageRect.origin.y + imageRect.size.height + kPadding, _pageSize.width - kPadding*2, 4) 
             withColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[self finishPDF];
```

To give you some context, finishPDF, setupPDFDocumentNamed, beginPDFPage, addImage and addText are all working methods, and are all part of the tutorial I'm linking below. Felt that it was too much to dump into one SO answer...

More on that here-
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generating-pdf-documents--mobile-11265